# Execute Multiple HTTP Requests in Synchronous Steps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a list of users and I want to make an API call for each one, then if all the results are a specific value for all users make a different API call for each one again checking for a specific value for all users. If all checks out I want to display a success message.

I want to send all of the http calls out for each user, then wait for them all to return before proceeding to the next step.

The following code is what I have so far, the problem is that the success message fires for each user and it loops through each user. I'm struggling to convert each step to accept a list of users.

```
runAllChecks = function () {
    var users = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "User1"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "User2"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "User3"
    }
    ];
    users.forEach(function (user) {
        step1(user).then(function (data) {
            if (data.result === true) {
                return step2(user);
            } else {
                $scope.userErrors.push('Error on step1 from user ' + user.name);
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
            if (data !== undefined) {
                if (data.result === true) {
                    return step3(user);
                } else {
                    $scope.userErrors.push('Error on step2 from user ' + user.name);
                }
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
            if (data !== undefined) {
                if (data.result === true) {
                    alert("done!");
                } else {
                    $scope.userErrors.push('Error on step3 from user ' + user.name);
                }
            }
        });
    });
};

var step1 = function (user) {
    return $.get("https://api.xyz.com/step1/" + user.id).fail(function (response) {
        $scope.httpError = true;
        return $q.reject(response);
    });
};

var step2 = function (user) {
    return $.get("https://api.xyz.com/step2/" + user.id).fail(function (response) {
        $scope.httpError = true;
        return $q.reject(response);
    });
};

var step3 = function (user) {
    return $.get("https://api.xyz.com/step3/" + user.id).fail(function (response) {
        $scope.httpError = true;
        return $q.reject(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: so you need to process all step1's and only when all have completed do all step 2's etc?

Comment: @jaromanda-x correct, after all step1's if all data.result === true then proceed to do all step2's

Comment: @jaromanda-x What happened to your answer? I reviewed it yesterday, however today when I went to test it the answer is gone.

Comment: It was full of wrong :)